# Populate list with Types

Tags: f#, fsharp.data.sqlclient

Im trying to populate list with my own type.

```
let getUsers =
    use connection = openConnection()
    let getString = "select * from Accounts"
    use sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(getString, connection)
    try
        let usersList = [||]
        use reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
        while reader.Read() do
            let floresID = reader.GetString 0
            let exName = reader.GetString 1
            let exPass = reader.GetString 2
            let user = [floresID=floresID; exName=exName; exPass=exPass]
            // what here?
            ()
    with
        | :? SqlException as e -> printfn "Došlo k chybě úrovni připojení:\n %s" e.Message
        | _ -> printfn "Neznámá výjimka."
```

In C# I would just add new object into `userList`. How can I add new `user` into list? Or is it better approach to get some sort of list with data from database?

Comment: If you can already get the list you need from the database, that would probably be the best way. Other than that, you could use `ResizeArray<_>`, which is .NET's `System.Collections.Generic.List<_>`. `usersList` currently is an array, and arrays can never be added to in .NET.

Comment: What database are you accessing and is there a specific reason to use ADO? You should try accessing it with a type provider. Either way, instead of an array try getting back a seq (IEnumerable) of Records.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is with a type provider, so you can abstract away the database. You can use [SqlDataConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/accessing-a-sql-database) for SQLServer, [SqlProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) for everything (incl. SQLServer), and also [SQLClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) for SQLServer.

Here is an example with postgres's dvdrental (sample) database for SQLProvider:

```
#r @"..\packages\SQLProvider.1.0.33\lib\FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"
#r @"..\packages\Npgsql.3.1.8\lib\net451\Npgsql.dll"

open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open Npgsql
open NpgsqlTypes
open System.Linq
open System.Xml
open System.IO
open System.Data

let [<Literal>] dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL
let [<Literal>] connString1  = @"Server=localhost;Database=dvdrental;User Id=postgres;Password=root"
let [<Literal>] resPath = @"C:\Users\userName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Postgre2\packages\Npgsql.3.1.8\lib\net451"
let [<Literal>] indivAmount = 1000
let [<Literal>] useOptTypes  = true

//create the type for the database, based on the connection string, etc. parameters
type sql =  SqlDataProvider<dbVendor,connString1,"",resPath,indivAmount,useOptTypes>
//set up the datacontext, ideally you would use `use` here :-)
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
let actorTbl = ctx.Public.Actor //alias the table

//set up the type, in this case  Records:
type ActorName = {
    firstName:string
    lastName:string}

//extract the data with a query expression, this gives you type safety and intellisense over SQL (but also see the SqlClient type provider above):
let qry = query {
            for row in actorTbl do
            select ({firstName=row.FirstName;lastName=row.LastName})
                } 
//seq is lazy so do all kinds of transformations if necessary then manifest it into a list or array:
qry  |> Seq.toArray
```

The two important parts are defining the Actor record, and then in the query extracting the fields into a sequence of Actor records. You can then manifest into a list or array if necessary.

But you can also stick to your original solution. In that case just wrap the `.Read()` into a `seq`:

First define the type:

```
type User = {
    floresID: string
    exName: string 
    exPass: string
}
```

Then extract the data:

```
let recs = cmd.ExecuteReader() // execute the SQL Command
//extract the users into a sequence of records:
let users = 
    seq {
         while recs.Read() do
             yield {floresID=recs.[0].ToString()
                    exName=recs.[1].ToString()
                    exPass=recs.[2].ToString()
                   }
        } |> Seq.toArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code, you can use list expression:

```fsharp
let getUsers =
    use connection = openConnection()
    let getString = "select * from Accounts"
    use sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(getString, connection)
    try
        [
            use reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
            while reader.Read() do
                let floresID = reader.GetString 0
                let exName = reader.GetString 1
                let exPass = reader.GetString 2
                let user = [floresID=floresID; exName=exName; exPass=exPass]
                yield user
        ]
    with
        | :? SqlException as e -> failwithf "Došlo k chybě úrovni připojení:\n %s" e.Message
        | _ -> failwithf "Neznámá výjimka."
```

That being said, I'd use FSharp.Data.SqlClient library so all of that boiler plate becomes a single line with added benefit of type safety (if you change the query, the code will have compile time error which are obvious to fix).